# Paypal Transaction in a Pop-up

Tags: php, javascript, paypal

Is it possible to do Paypal Transaction in a pop-up!

Comment: Can, you describe it somemore

Comment: Which option are you using for Paypal integration. One where you make backend calls to them or redirect the user to Paypal's website?

Comment: we are redirecting the user to Paypal website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Digital Goods for Express Checkout](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_IntegratingExpressCheckoutDG).  There's a [wizard](https://www.paypal-labs.com/integrationwizard/ecdigitalgoods/intro.php) for PHP and Java, but for other languages, you'll have to roll your own code, and the documentation isn't great.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. **­** *­* **­** *­* **­** *­* **­** *­* **­** *­*